# Preimage of a specific size

Tags: combinatorics, functions

My kid has this problem in a discrete-math course:

> How many functions $f:\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ have the property that, for all $i$, the inverse image of $i$ does not have size $i$ (that is, $\left|f^{-1}[\{i\}]\right|\ne i$)?

One can of course list all of them, but I suspect there's a nicer way that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Maybe try counting the opposite, the number of functions such that you *do* have preimages of those sizes for at least one such $i$.  Note that it is impossible for the preimage of $4$ to have size $4$ while *also* having preimages of anything else be nonempty, and similarly you can't have a preimage of size two and of three at the same time as that would need too many elements, so there shouldn't be very many intersections needing to be considered when performing inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is some confusion, I'll weigh in with my answer as well.

Apply inclusion-exclusion.  We will start with the $4^4=256$ total different functions possible.  We then subtract those who violated the condition that $1$ had one preimage, those who had that $2$ had two preimages and so on.  As a part of inclusion-exclusion, we then add back those who simultaneously had one preimage for $1$ and two preimages for $2$ and so on... noting that many of these cases including those who would simultaneously violate three or more conditions are impossible.

We get:

$$256 - 4\cdot 3^3 - \binom{4}{2}\cdot 3^2 - \binom{4}{3}\cdot 3^1 - 1 + 4\cdot 3\cdot 2 + 4 = 109$$

The value of $4\cdot 3\cdot 2$ in the above for example was corresponding to $1$ with one preimage and $2$ with two preimages.  This is calculated by choosing what the preimage of $1$ is (4 choices), choosing what two elements are the preimage of $2$ ($\binom{3}{2}=3$ choices), and then for the final element choosing where it gets mapped (2 choices).

This agrees with the OP's attempt and answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's one function such that the preimage of 4 has size 4.

If the preimage of 3 has size 3, there are four choices for which element doesn't map to 3, and two choices for what it maps to (I'm ignoring the possibility that it's 1 for now, will cover that later), for eight functions all together.

If the preimage of 2 has size 2, there are six choices for which elements don't map to 2, and five choices for what they map to (I'm ignoring the possibility that precisely one of them maps to 1 for now, will cover that later), for thirty functions all together.

If the preimage of 1 has size 1, there are four choices for which element maps to 1, and 27 choices of the other mappings, for 108 functions.

So there are a total of $256-1-8-30-108=109$ functions that meet the criteria in the question.

Hat-tip: [JMoravitz](/users/179297/jmoravitz), in [a comment](/questions/4757966/preimage-of-a-specific-size?noredirect=1#comment10100169_4757966)

Answer (score 0):

Let us partition the domain set and look for maps satisfying the given conditions.

- $4=4.$ All elements map to one of $\{1,2,3\}$. $3$ functions.
- $4=3+1.$ $3$ elements map to one of $\{1,2,4\}$ while $1$ element maps to one unused of $\{2,3,4\}$. $28$ functions.
- $4=2+2$. Two elements each map to two of $\{1,3,4\}$. $18$ functions.
- $4=1+1+1+1$. One element matches to each of $\{1,2,3,4\}$; this is not allowed. $0$ functions.
- $4=2+1+1$. Two elements match to one of $\{1,3,4\}$. Remaining two match to two unused of $\{2,3,4\}$. $60$ functions.

This gives total of $3+28+18+0+60=109$ functions.